# Grounding Brass Fixture

Tags: electrical, lighting, grounding

The light fixture has no grounding wire attached. Since it’s all brass and going on the porch I think the exterior must be grounded. Do I just affix a wire to the metal somehow? Probably at the threaded coupler between the socket and the fixture.

[image: plastic light socket 250V 2A E14 with E12 adapter. Threaded coupler in interior of nautical brass wall fixture]

[image: exterior pieces of nautical brass wall fixture]

Comment: If adding a ground wire, a screw connection(Wire connected with a screw) is best, instead of depending of catching a wire in threads.  If all brass, then easiest spot for a screw will work.

Comment: Let's see the whole thing including the back of the canopy.  That is where ground wires are normally attached.

Comment: What kind of a wall box is it attaching to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain grounding lugs which are rings that fit over the 1/8" pipe nipples widely used in light fixture construction, and have an integral wire attached. The wire is simply spliced with the incoming circuit ground wire. The lug would be held tightly against the fixture body using a nut and lockwasher.

Example: https://antiquelampsupply.com/products/1-8-ip-grounding-lug-w-bare-copper-wire